# OSX El Capitan python install cryptography fail

Tags: python, macos

I tried

sudo pip install cryptography

And the error message is

> Collecting cryptography
>    Using cached cryptography-1.3.2-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.4.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1>=0.1.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
>   Collecting setuptools>=11.3 (from cryptography)
>     Using cached setuptools-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna>=2.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipaddress in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography)
>   Installing collected packages: setuptools, cryptography
>     Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
>       Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
>   Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
>       requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
>       paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
>       renames(path, new_path)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 267, in renames
>       shutil.move(old, new)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
>       copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
>       raise Error, errors
>   Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.py', '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.pyc', '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-p7Ywro-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]

Then I searched some post and tried

brew install pkg-config libffi openssl

> Warning: pkg-config-0.28 already installed
>   Warning: libffi-3.0.13 already installed
>   Warning: openssl-1.0.2d_1 already installed

and

CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" sudo pip install cryptography==0.8

I got this error message:

> src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/**pycache**/_Cryptography_cffi_f3e4673fx399b1113.c:217:10: fatal error: 'openssl/aes.h' file not found
>      #include 
>                ^
>      1 error generated.
>      error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip-build-MxT6op/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-G6b8Y_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-MxT6op/cryptography/

I also tried

brew install pkg-config libffi openssl

env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography

and got this

> Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
>       Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:
>   Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
>       requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
>       paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
>       renames(path, new_path)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 267, in renames
>       shutil.move(old, new)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
>       copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
>       raise Error, errors
>   Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.py', '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.pyc', '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-aYpqDT-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]

Please help me to get this fixed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was:

```
sudo brew reinstall python
```

Comment: I helped me too, though I ran `brew` without `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this fixe by the following commands:

```
brew reinstall python

ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" \
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" pip install cryptography

brew link —force openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

To install cryptography package on Mac OS El Capitan. As explained in Cryptography installation doc

env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography